# I am trying to create an accumulator function for an vector of sets. But I keep getting strange results

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, data-mining

Basically, I have a vector of sets.  I'd like to merge the sets based on a criteria (you can see this criteria in the if statement).  More than two sets may be merged.  Here is an example data set:

```
[{:name "corner", :matched-shape "corner", :direction :e, :rotation 1}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "corner", :direction :e, :rotation 2}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "corner", :direction :s, :rotation 2}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "corner", :direction :s, :rotation 3}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "pipe", :direction :s, :rotation 0}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "pipe", :direction :e, :rotation 1}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "pipe", :direction :s, :rotation 2}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "pipe", :direction :e, :rotation 3}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "cross", :direction :e, :rotation 0}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "cross", :direction :s, :rotation 0}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "cross", :direction :e, :rotation 1}
                                        {:name "corner", :matched-shape "cross", :direction :s, :rotation 1}]
```

I have tried dozens of solutions but none of them work.  Here is my code:

```
(defn merge-symmetry-table [symmetry-table]
  (filter #(if-not (nil? %) %) 
          (loop [[x y & remaining] symmetry-table result []]
            (if-not (empty? y)
              (if (and (= (:name x) (:name y))
                       (= (:direction x) (:direction y)))
                (recur [(concat-symmetries x y) remaining] result)
                (recur [conj y remaining] [result x]))
              (conj result x)))))
```

and my output as of now:

```
([]
 {:name "corner", :direction :e, :matched-shapes ["corner" 1 "corner" 2]}
 {:name nil, :direction nil, :matched-shapes [[nil nil nil nil] nil nil]})
```

I'm sure there is a nicer way to do this, but I would like to know what is exactly wrong with my code.  I've gone it over literally fifty times and I cannot understand what is wrong.  Thank you for your help.

I'm not sure if I am allowed to express dissatisfaction here (and I do not wish to bother anyone), but I have had absolutely immense difficulty dealing with data in this programming language.  Admittedly, this is my first project in this language and I'm mostly a self-taught coder.  But nesting vectors inside vectors and using just "keymaps" has made it an absolute nightmare trying to get anything done let alone organize data in a cohesive manner.  I probably rewrite my functions at least ten times just to get them to return what I want.  There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: What should the output be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use either `partition-by`:

```
(defn merge-symmetry-table [data]
  (->> data
       (partition-by (juxt :name :direction))
       (map (partial apply concat-symmetries))))
```

or `group-by`:

```
(defn merge-symmetry-table [data]
  (->> data
       (group-by (juxt :name :direction))
       vals
       (map (partial apply concat-symmetries))))
```

Comment: group-by seems to organize the results the way I need.  However my concat-symmetries function works by feeding two entries at a time.  It's meant to be sort of an accumulator that works on pairs.  If the arguments meet the criteria, it will merge them together.  Otherwise, it will print off the previous merged pairs and start again with the next two arguments.  It's really this part of the logic that I have had trouble implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion, I was able to work out a solution.  It uses the suggested code and I reformulated my concat function as a reducer and it works!  Here's my code:

```
(defn merge-symmetry-table [data]
  (let [symmetry-table (sort-by (juxt :name :direction) data)]
    (->> symmetry-table
         (partition-by (juxt :name :direction))
         (map #(reduce concat-symmetries %)))))
```